# Recurrence relations only have solutions of the form $1, t, t^2, t^3, \ldots$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

**Background**

I'm trying to re-learn recurrence relations, and all the books I'm finding are a bit cryptic on the matter.

Here's my issue:

Essentially, the books very quickly skip to **second-order linear homogeneous recurrence relations with constant terms**. That's fine. Lower-order relations are simple arithmetic/geometric sequences, and those are taught in earlier classes.

Alright, we have the general form, $$a_k = Aa_{k-1} + Ba_{k-2}$$ where $A,B$ are constants and $k\geq 2$.

Instantly, the books tell you to focus on solutions of the form $1, t, t^2, t^3, \ldots$, *supposing* it has a solution of that form.

From there, we derive that solving $t^2 - At - B = 0$ gives us the desired $t$-values that solve the recurrence relation.

But then it doesn't seem to come back to the fact that there was a *supposition* made earlier. What about possible solutions that *don't* take the form $1, t, t^2, t^3, \ldots$?

**Question**

Do the solutions to this type of recurrence relation always satisfy this form?

If not, is there are reason why the other types of solutions are glossed over? Are they considered "next semester" level of math?

Comment: If the characteristic polynomial has distinct roots then all solutions are linear combinations of solutions of this form. Otherwise you don't get all solutions and you need to do something more complicated. This all gets much clearer once you learn enough linear algebra to understand what's going on here in terms of eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Comment: In some cases, the solutions are of the form $n^kt^n$ for integers $k.$ More generally, $p(n)t^n$ where $p$ is a polynomial of degree less than some number.

Comment: Note that the space of sequences obeying this recurrence relation is a vector space, and that each such sequence $a_k$ is uniquely determined by $a_0, a_1$.  This tells you that the space of all solutions is $2$-dimensional.  So, if you find two linearly independent solutions, you automatically have all solutions.

Comment: The generating function approach to solve recurrences (as in the first few sections of Wilf's generatingfunctionology https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf ) allows one to derive the closed form without making any guesses like this; possibly you will find that congenial.

Comment: It is not true that all solutions are of the form $a_k=t^k$. You can also have solutions of the form $a_k=k^nt^k$, and linear combinations of these basic solutions.